# Vertical space between buttons in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I want to customise my UIAlertController ,change the background and text Colour of the  cancel button ,also to have a vertical space between buttons

Any Help?

Comment: Look here - https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=alert

Comment: nice collections. I never know about this site!! Thanks for sharing it @SamB

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at URBNAlert
https://github.com/urbn/URBNAlert
[image]